# getting data from servlet class

Tags: java, servlets

I have a class that gets data from the servlet like so :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");{
        ServletOutputStream  out = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
            out.println("<html><head><title>" +  "</title></head>");
            out.println("<body><h1>" +  "</h1>");
            name = request.getParameter("username" );
            message = "hi there";
            //String  comment = request.getParameter( "comment" );
            out.println("Name:" + name + "<BR>");
            //out.println("Comment: " + comment + "<BR>");
        }
        catch(Throwable  t ) {
            out.println("<P><pre>");
            t.printStackTrace( new PrintStream(out) );
            out.println ("</pre><P>");
        }
        out.println ("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

And that works fine, but I want to use the name parameter in a different class on the server too. Can I use something like :

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("package", "name");
```

And call the attribute from the class like that? Or is there another way I can save the value in the servlet context or in the servlet so I can call it again? all i really want to do is after the servlet is loaded, to keep the last value it's processed somewhere and use that in another class when needed.

All Help is appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 1):

`getServletContext()` is one of the ways to share data between servelts. So, yes your approach should be fine.

If the data is specific to user, instead of `getServletContext()`, it is better to use `HttpSession`.

Comment: How can I call getServletContext() in the other class though? How can i pass it the servlet context of this class? Thanks

Comment: ServletContext is global across application, if the other class is "Servlet", you can again do getServletContext and do getAttribute.  If other class is not Servlet, then you need to context in servlet which comes before the class and getAttribute there and pass it to other class.

Comment: The other class I want to call the data from isn't actually a servlet though, sorry! Could you please elaborate on the second part, I don't fully understand, is there an example I could view?

Comment: when other class being called is it on subsequent request (or) same request?

Comment: it's subsequent, its gets called later in a different set of transactions
Thanks for your help again

Comment: So, different transaction execution also starts from some other servlet right? there do getServletContext() and pass this context as parameter to your other class.

Comment: I'll try and see what happens, thanks. if your still interested ill post back here what happens :)

Comment: Sure, that is what SO is for and if this answered helped you, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking tick mark

Comment: passing the context as a parameter hasn't worked because the other class is in a different thread of execution to my servlet I think. :( I think I'm close to getting it working though :)

Comment: context is not dependent on thread (as long as that thread is maintained by container and for the same application). Play around those areas, you will get it.